# Can i disable animations on Preference Screen?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm using Android PreferenceScreen. One screen is to be shown only for administrators.

Therefor, in my fragment onResume, i have a call:

```
adminScreen.setVisible(user.isAdmin());//Preference
```

However when the fragment is shown, the preference is first shown, then there's a short aninmation where the row disappears vertically, and the rows under it are shifted up.

I would like the row to disappear instantly, but can't see how i can make it happen. There are no methods i can see, and the **android:animateLayoutChanges** has no effect anywhere in my preferences.xml

Does anyone know if there is a way to disable this animation?

Answer (score 4):

Disable the animations on the RecycleView it's using to display the preferences:

```
  @Override
  public RecyclerView onCreateRecyclerView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle state) {
    final RecyclerView view = super.onCreateRecyclerView(inflater, parent, state);
    view.setItemAnimator(null);
    view.setLayoutAnimation(null);
    return view;
  }
```

However the preference to be removed will still flash briefly, so a best solution is to initially hide them in XML using `app:isPreferenceVisible="false"`, and then show them when needed using [setVisible(true)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/Preference.html#setVisible(boolean))

Comment: Bit late answering to this, but still :) Thanks, but i don't want any animations at all. Your suggestion will remove the flash, but it will still animate the "appearance" of the setting. I guess it's better than the flash though.

Comment: app:isPreferenceVisible="false" is not a solution, because it animates in the opposite case, when you setVisible(true). I call setVisible() in the Fragment onResume(), because preferences visibility depends on variable conditions, and I'd like that Preferences would not animate each time I open the Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

With the supposition that you are using a PreferenceFragmentCompat, you can avoid initial animation calling adminScreen.setVisible() before the onResume. If you do that just after the setPreferencesFromResource() or the setPreferenceScreen(), the animation would not be done.